# Simplify Boolean Algebra Expreesion

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

According to WolframAlpha, $$(A_3\cdot(A_2+A_1+A_0))+(\overline{A_3}\cdot A_2 \cdot\overline{A_1}\cdot\overline{A_0})$$ should simplify to $$=A_3\cdot A_0+A_3\cdot A_1+A_2\cdot\overline{A_1}\cdot\overline{A_0}$$.
But how? Here is my attempt:

[image]

Specifically, I don't know how to get from $$A_2\cdot(A_3+\overline{A_1}\cdot\overline{A_0})$$
to
$$A_2\cdot\overline{A_1}\cdot\overline{A_0}$$
Did I miss something? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, the *subexpression* $A_2(A_3+A_1'A_0')$ is *not* equivalent to $A_2A_1'A_0'$

So, did you do something wrong?

No, you did everything right.

It is the fact that this subexpression appears in the context of the larger expression as a whole that you can simplify it.

Indeed, how in the step before it you yourself go from $A_3+A_3'A_1'A_0'$ to $A_3+A_1'A_0'$ ... Whoa, is that because $A_3'A_1'A_0'$ is equivalent to $A_1'A_0'$?  No, of course not! Rather, it is the fact that you also have $A_3$ that you can reduce the expression $A_3'A_1'A_0'$ to $A_1'A_0'$

Something similar is going on here well: we'll need the fact that we also have $A_3A_1$ and $A_3A_0$ in order to simplify $A_2(A_3+A_1'A_0')$ to $A_2A_1'A_0'$

This is not easy though, as you can see from the Answer by @Manx

Still, using the [Consensus Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consensus_theorem), it can be made a little easier:

\begin{align}
&A_2\cdot (A_3+(\overline{A_1}\cdot\overline{A_0}))+A_3\cdot A_0+A_3\cdot A_1\\
=&A_2\cdot A_3+A_2\cdot\overline{A_1}\cdot\overline{A_0}+A_3\cdot A_0+A_3\cdot A_1\tag*{Distributive law}\\
=&A_2\cdot A_3+A_2\cdot\overline{A_1}\cdot\overline{A_0}+A_3\cdot (A_0+A_1)\tag*{Distributive law}\\
=&A_2\cdot A_3+A_2\cdot\overline{A_1+A_0}+A_3\cdot (A_0+A_1)\tag*{DeMorgan}\\
=&A_2\cdot\overline{A_1+A_0}+A_3\cdot (A_0+A_1)\tag*{Consensus}\\
=&A_2\cdot\overline{A_1}\cdot\overline{A_0} + A_3\cdot A_0+A_3\cdot A_1\tag*{DeMorgan, Distribution}\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Your attempts are correct so far, try apply distributive law for the first part, can you see why we don't need $A_2\cdot A_3$ in this statement ?

**Answer:**

\begin{align}
&A_2\cdot (A_3+(\overline{A_1}\cdot\overline{A_0}))+A_3\cdot A_0+A_3\cdot A_1\\
=&A_2\cdot A_3+A_2\cdot\overline{A_1}\cdot\overline{A_0}+A_3\cdot A_0+A_3\cdot A_1\tag*{Distributive law}\\
=&A_2\cdot A_3\cdot(1)+A_2\cdot\overline{A_1}\cdot\overline{A_0}+A_3\cdot A_0+A_3\cdot A_1\tag*{Identity law}\\
=&A_2\cdot A_3\cdot(A_1+\overline{A_1})+A_2\cdot\overline{A_1}\cdot\overline{A_0}+A_3\cdot A_0+A_3\cdot A_1\tag*{Negation law}\\
=&A_2\cdot A_3\cdot A_1+A_2\cdot A_3\cdot\overline{A_1}+A_2\cdot\overline{A_1}\cdot\overline{A_0}+A_3\cdot A_0+A_3\cdot A_1\tag*{Distributive law}\\
=&A_2\cdot A_3\cdot A_1+A_3\cdot A_1+A_2\cdot A_3\cdot\overline{A_1}+A_2\cdot\overline{A_1}\cdot\overline{A_0}+A_3\cdot A_0\tag*{Reordering}\\
=&A_3\cdot A_1+A_2\cdot A_3\cdot\overline{A_1}+A_2\cdot\overline{A_1}\cdot\overline{A_0}+A_3\cdot A_0\tag*{Absorption law}\\
=&A_3\cdot A_1+A_2\cdot A_3\cdot\overline{A_1}(1)+A_2\cdot\overline{A_1}\cdot\overline{A_0}+A_3\cdot A_0\tag*{Identity law}\\
=&A_3\cdot A_1+A_2\cdot A_3\cdot\overline{A_1}(A_0+\overline{A_0})+A_2\cdot\overline{A_1}\cdot\overline{A_0}+A_3\cdot A_0\tag*{Negation law}\\
=&A_3\cdot A_1+A_2\cdot A_3\cdot\overline{A_1}\cdot A_0+A_2\cdot A_3\cdot\overline{A_1}\cdot\overline{A_0}\tag*{Distributive law}\\&+A_2\cdot\overline{A_1}\cdot\overline{A_0}+A_3\cdot A_0\\
=&A_3\cdot A_1+A_2\cdot\overline{A_1}\cdot A_3\cdot A_0+A_3\cdot A_0\tag*{Reordering}\\&
+A_2\cdot A_3\cdot\overline{A_1}\cdot\overline{A_0}+A_2\cdot\overline{A_1}\cdot\overline{A_0}\\
=&A_3\cdot A_1+A_3\cdot A_0\tag*{Absorption law}+A_2\cdot\overline{A_1}\cdot\overline{A_0}\\
\end{align}